# Custom hash that works with pointer and reference

Tags: c++

I want to create a reusable IdHash and IdEqualTo class that takes const instances (reference, raw pointer, or smart pointer), and returns the hash value or the compare result.

```
template<class Entity, class Id>
struct IdFunc {
    typedef typename std::function<const Id& (const Entity&)> type;
};

template<class Entity, class Id>
struct IdHash {
public:    
    explicit IdHash(const typename IdFunc<Entity, Id>::type& idFunc) : idFunc_(idFunc) {}
    std::size_t operator()(const Entity& o) const {
        return std::hash<Id>()(idFunc_(o));
    }  
private:
    typename IdFunc<Entity, Id>::type idFunc_;     
}; 
// IdEqualTo follows the same pattern
```

My first attempt works with `unordered_set<MyClass, IdHash<string, MyClass>, IdEqualTo<...>>`.  Since MyClass will be a inheritance hierarchy instead of a single type, I need to switch to pointers: `unordered_set<unique_ptr<MyClass>, IdHash<string, MyClass>, ...>`.  Now I need a version of the operator that takes unique_ptr&.  I provided the following

```
    std::size_t operator()(const Entity* o) const {
        return std::hash<Id>()(idFunc_(*o));
    }
```

hoping `unique_ptr<MyClass>&` can somehow be converted to `MyClass*`.  It didn't work.  Since this utility is supposed to transcend storage type, how can I make it work with reference, raw pointer, or smart pointer?

See [code sample](https://ideone.com/C0B6zp).

Thanks.

Comment: Add an overload `std::size_t operator()(const std::unique_ptr<E> &o) const`?

Comment: @immibis How about if I need to use other pointer types like shared_ptr<E> or E* next time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic conversion from smart pointers to raw pointers (though you can use `get()`).

Specialize your templates for smart pointers, this is the way it is done in standard library and in boost.

```
template <class Inner, class Id>
struct IdHash<std::unique_ptr<Inner>, Id> {
   typedef std::unique_ptr<Inner> PtrType;
   std::size_t operator() (const PtrType &pointer) const {
       return std::hash<Id>()(idFunc_(pointer.get());
   }
};
```

You may also want to create `std::hash<Id>` instance only once instead of every time you call `operator()`.